# Will $n$ for $A^n=\mathbb{I}$, where $A$ is any finite operation on a finite group and $\mathbb{I}$ is the identity operator, always be finite?

Tags: group-theory, permutations, symmetric-groups, rubiks-cube

Will $n$ for $A^n=\mathbb{I}$, where $A$ is any finite operation on a finite group and $\mathbb{I}$ is the identity operator, always be finite?

Consider for instance a finite sequence of moves (operations) on a Rubik's cube. How can we show that if we just carry out the same sequence of moves enough (but finitely many) times, we will always end up in the starting configuration again?

(I suspect that this is an elementary result in Group theory, but I haven't gotten around to studying it yet, so please bear with me.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since there are only finitely many states, you'll come across a state twice eventually, so there must be $k > m$ such that $A^k = A^m$. Define $n := k-m$. Now $A^n = A^{k-m} = A^kA^{-m} = A^mA^{-m} = I$.

Comment: Does the rule $A^{xy}=A^xA^y$ hold for any operator?

Comment: You must mean $A^{x+y}=A^xA^y$. In this case, the left hand side is defined as "Do $A$ $(x+y)$ times" and the right hand side is defined as "Do $A$ $y$ times, then do $A$ $x$ times." So it's clear that they are the same.

Comment: @Max Yes, of course that's what I mean (d'oh!)! All right, that's good; I'm always wary to just go with my intuition on the general cases.. all too often, there's some weird counter-example. Thanks!

Comment: "Young man, in mathematics you don't understand things. You just get used to them." -John von Neumann